# Wording at the beginning of Nitzavim

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grammar-dikduk, parashat-nitzavim

Parshas Nitzavim begins ([Devarim 29:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9993#v=9)-[11](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9993#v=11)):

> א**תם** נצב**ים** היום כל**כם**... ראשי**כם** שבטי**כם** זקני**כם** ושטרי**כם** כל איש ישראל. טפ**כם** נשי**כם** וגר**ך** אשר בקרב מחני**ך** מחטב עצי**ך** עד שאב מימי**ך**. לעבר**ך**

The first verse-and-a-half is written in the second-person plural. Halfway through verse 10, it suddenly switches to the singular. Why?

Comment: כלי יקר has an explanation for verses 11-12 but not afaict for verse 10. חזקוני similarly.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/74685/19365

Answer (score 2):

In chumash, plural means that the people are being addressed as individuals, while singular means they are being addressed as a nation.
The point of the first half is that each individual Jew is present. The verse then adds that the nation's adjuncts - the convert,etc. - are present, hence the whole nation is present. Now the nation as a whole will be bound by covenant. The adjuncts cannot be referred to in singular, since they are neither the parties of the covenant, nor do they belong to each Jew, rather only to the nation as a whole.

Comment: Adding a source or other evidence for your claims would improve your answer's value.